# NSLocalizedString should be used directly for exporting XLIFF?

Tags: xcode, swift, localization, internationalization, xliff

I used to use `NSLocalizedString` by custom function.

For example, to access `Profile.strings`, I define this function:

`func LocalizedProfile(key: String, comment: String?) {
  NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "Profile", comment: comment ?? "")
}`

And, called like this:

`let localized = LocalizedProfile("Submit", comment: "For registration")`

This method works fine except for exporting XLIFF.

On the Xcode 6.3.2, executting `Export for localization`throws error:

[image]

To get error information, I executed via command line:

`xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath ./xliff -project MyApp.xcodeproj -exportLanguage ja`

And, I got this error:

`Bad entry in file /Users/mono/Documents/Git/MyApp/Localization.swift (line = 29): Argument is not a literal string.`

Defining custom localization method is very useful for me, but I also want to use exporting XLIFF feature.

Are there any methods to resolve this demands?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue... I've also tried to substituted keys with string constants.... but it doesn't work. The only solution seems to use a string directly as key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Export For Localization` and `xcodebuild -exportLocalizations` both generate strings files by looking for invocations of `NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)` in code and uses the static values passed into the parameters to create the appropriate strings files.

This means that the only values you can pass into `key`, `comment`, `value`, and `tableName` are string literals.

Since you're using a wrapper function around `NSLocalizedString(_:comment:)` to localize your strings, the only time Xcode sees you calling `NSLocalizedString(_:comment:)` is in that one wrapper function with non-string-literal values, which is invalid.

What you really want to do instead is call `NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:comment:)` directly.

Alternatively, you can call `Bundle.localizedString(forKey:value:table:)` in your wrapper function, but then you have to manually create your own strings files for those key-value pairs.

```swift
/// - parameter comment: This value is ignored, but should be provided for 
///   context at the call site about the requested localized string.
func LocalizedProfile(key: String, comment: String?) -> String {
    return Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: "Profile")
}
```